# Xamarin Forms - Android: HttpClient.PostAsync() crashes application

Tags: android, xamarin, httpclient

i am facing a situation like the very first one reported. I am running my app on an LG G6 running Android 8.0. When i call "await httpClient.PostAsync()", the application crashes. However, when i use a blocking call, i.e. "httpClient.PostAsync().Result", the application runs fine. I've setup the app to to compile using Android 7, with "Minimum Target version" set to 4.4 and "Target Android version" set to Android 7.0.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: Exception/StackTrace? Crash report from `logcat`?

Comment: Thanks Bruno Caceiro & SushiHangover Let me try to get a log. May take a bit of time since it will be my first time on the platform.